# How can I ignore a MySQL index using ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) has syntax for ignoring queries. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 IGNORE INDEX (i1);
```

How can I build a query like the above using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found you can specify a custom `from clause` like so:

```
T1.from("t1 ignore index (i1)")
```

Semi-related documentation: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/from